# How to theme Views Bulk Operation Pages

Tags: theming, views

In views bulk operations, you can select fields and then edit them by clicking on "Modify Entity Values".

When you do this, a screen appears asking you to select the entities you wish to modify and the values you wish to set. **Is there a way of using a custom template to theme this screen?**

---

---

**Additional Info:**

The top part of the screen lists provides check boxes for all the entities the user can edit. The user has to tick a check box to edit an entity. The bottom of the screen lists all the values that can be set.

I would like to use Jquery so the values on the bottom only appear when the corresponding check box at the top has been ticked. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there anything special you cannot do with standar drupal theming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, I think you should look at preprocessing the VBO form. You can then theme it as you would any other form.